# JavaScript binary reduce function: why is 16 + 0 returning 0?

Tags: javascript, binary, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a function that takes in 8-bit binary and gives you the sum.

I'm having trouble doing `num + num`, of all things.

In my reduce function, I create a sum and add together the value of the number translated in binary:

```
const enumerableBinaryMap = {
    0: 128,
    1: 64,
    2: 32,
    3: 16,
    4: 8,
    5: 4,
    6: 2,
    7: 1
};

function sum (arr) {
    return arr.reduce((sum, val, index) => {
        return sum + val === 1 ? enumerableBinaryMap[index] : 0;
    }, 0);
}

sum([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]); // 1, should be 17
```

The problem occurs when I get to the first 1 in the array of binary numbers.

For instance, take a look below at the values on each call of the reducer:

1. sum = 0,  val = 0, index = 0
2. sum = 0,  val = 0, index = 1
3. sum = 0,  val = 0, index = 2
4. sum = 0,  val = 1, index = 3
5. sum = 16, val = 0, index = 4
6. sum = 0,  val = 0, index = 5  <--- BOOM!

As you can see above, the return value of the 5th call in the reducer is the culprit here. Why does sum equal 0 on the 6th call? It should still be 16 because we returned 16 + 0?

And I can verify my implementation of reduce works, because the following below works, and it's essentially the same thing I'm doing:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce((sum, val) => sum + val, 0); /// 15
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: You need to add `sum` to what gets returned inside the `reduce`.

Comment: Yes, that works, but why is it necessary? The example I showed at the end of my question shows that just returning `sum` + some arbitrary number still adds it to the return value, so it shouldn't matter in this case either.

Comment: The reduce should be `return sum + (val === 1 ? enumerableBinaryMap[index] : 0);`

Comment: Hmm okay that did it, so the problem must be associativity then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a problem of [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). The code you've shown is interpreted as

```
return (((sum + val) === 1) ? enumerableBinaryMap[index] : 0);
```

whereas you want

```
return (sum + ((val === 1) ? enumerableBinaryMap[index] : 0));
//            ^                                            ^
```

Add a couple of parenthesis to fix it or use

```
return val === 1 ? sum + enumerableBinaryMap[index] : sum;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Need to study more on associativity in JavaScript.